# Why does the Angular tag icon have a white background? It looks odd compared to other tags' icons

Tags: discussion, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

As I understand, icons are provided by sponsors, but are these adjustable in any way by SO?

The [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) icon is particularly ugly -- the whitespace around it looks like it was copy pasted from [Microsoft Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint). Perhaps it could be put more in line with the other icons and have a transparent background?

[image]

On the left is how it is, and on the right is how it could be.

Comment: care to provide a link? the only angular icon i can find on SO angular tags looks fine to me.

Comment: what OS / display hardware are you using...?

Comment: edited. I see it both on windows 7 and linux debian

Comment: @KevinB the icon from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/info), visible next to "About" at the top of the page

Comment: @Shog9 I also see this issue on Windows 10 with Chrome 72

Comment: I mean, if i look at it at 300% zoom it does look blurry, as most icons of that size do.

Comment: @KevinB it's not the blur, it's the white background

Comment: @Vlad274 That hardly qualifies as an "issue". There is a white background.

Comment: Eh... If Angular wants to pay SO to have an icon with an ugly background on the tag, that's their choice

Comment: @DavyM, you are correct. I have to zoom to more than 100% as well (no amazing eyesight :/). I think ErikA is correct, if the sponsor wants to pay, so be it.

Comment: Yay they "fixed" it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct that tags can be sponsored as part of an ad buy. While we can and do request changes from clients when it comes to creatives and sponsorships, we allow for the white background in this particular creative unit. One reason we allow for this, while not directly applicable to this tag and creative, is that an advertiser may have a logo similar in color to our tags, or have features that blend in without having a specific solid color background.

Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

That is very subjective. I have no problem with the look it gives on the page when at normal size. Why do you decide it's a problem?

I disagree with your preference.

Answer (score -1):

I totally agree that the icon of Angular should be with a transparent background, subjective or not, depends on how user looks at it or not, I think it should be following the scheme in Stack Overflow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You see here other icons are really clear and with a transparent background, Angular one looks odd.

**Especially** If we look at their official PRESSKIT: https://angular.io/presskit it is transparent indeed!

Keep all with a white background, or all transparent, I don't think mixing standards-way is comfortable or smooth for eyes.

Or at least maybe Stack Overflow should define some kind of standard or recommendations?

*P.S: 
I think some of the downvotes came from people thing that your issue is about "blurry", as I see in the comment section.*

---

**Edit**: Well, it seems they read this feedback, or they noticed the odd.

[image]

Comment: I would guess that whoever bought the sponsored background intended for it to look like it does and according to the answer from Will Westendorf that appears to the case.

Comment: @JoeW I agree, but still, he might be new to the community and don't know how things works, so I do really support his claim. not StackOverflow issue, but somehow this issue should be noticed by sponsorer, am I wrong?

Comment: Will works for us. He's one of our Ad Team members. If anyone's going to know whether it's intentional or not, he will. :D

Answer (score -6):

**I agree with it**

Because it looks a little bit weird because when we use this logo with another background color except white that not looks good.
I think they should have to convert into png

Comment: There is already an answer that states the same, did you consider upvoting it? And why would converting to PNG help?